# Why the derivatives and gradient are used interchangeably?

Tags: derivatives, gradient-descent

I am not good at mathematics and have been learning ML from Udacity.

In its tutorial video, the tutor mentioned

derivatives at time 4:24 https://youtu.be/9ILiZwbi9dA?t=264

and gradient across the whole video e.g. at time 3:03 https://youtu.be/9ILiZwbi9dA?t=184

So this makes me thinking derivatives and gradient are interchangeable.

Am I correct?

If not, what are the differences between Gradient and Derivative in laymen's language?(yes, I did searched the differences, but they are too mathematic. My hopeless not-math-capable brain cannot understand it but my curiosity keeps driving me to get it understood.... >_<)

and when to use gradient and when to use derivative?

Comment: For functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ they both mean the same thing! For functions say $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, there is no single derivative, there are directional derivatives are you have the gradient (you could argue you have the total derivative but wink wink, this is just the gradient again). For more general functions $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ the term total derivative or differential is more often used.

Comment: Im not comfortable to firmly say there is a difference.  Derivative is the term we hear as early as single variable differential calculus but gradient doesnt come up until multivariable differential calculus.  The gradient is just a vector comprising several partial derivatives.  Not really a practical difference. Both tell you the direction and magnitude of change. The latter used when there is more than one independent variable in a space.

Comment: @Pacciu correct me if I'm wrong, I do not think that questions I asked answers this question.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum thanks for your explanation. So just to confirm my understanding of your comment is actually what you mean: Derivative is used for single variable, whereas gradient is used for multivariable. They both tell the direction and magnitude of change. If my understanding of your comment is correct. Could you please post your comment as an answer? thanks

Comment: @OsamaGhani thanks for your comment. I have to admit that as a laymen of math, I am lost in the terms of mathematics. I don't understand the R, total derivative etc.